# ImageView moving behind Camera Surface View

Tags: android, android-layout, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

I am trying to place an imageview over a Camera surfaceview, when the application starts the imageview is on top of the camera preview but after a picture is taken and is set to the imageview the RelativeLayout that the camera preview is nested in moves forward when startpreview is called to start the camera again so the camera preview ends up above the imageview. There are buttons in the same layout placed after the imageview in the xml layout and those are not affected. If I don't start the camera again after a picture the imageview has it's image and is visible. Dumping the view hierarchy verifies the same. As far as I can tell this should be something fairly straight-forward, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

UPDATE: I have also attempted to add a completely new ImageView with the bitmap programmatically after the camera is started and that ImageView is moved behind as well.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/add_activity"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/beforeImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:id="@+id/close_camera"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_capture"
        android:text="Before"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/purple"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add_progress_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
public class AddActivity extends Activity {

    private Camera mCamera;
    CameraPreview mPreview;
    private RelativeLayout preview;
    boolean useFrontCamera = true;
    boolean tookBeforeImage = false;
    boolean tookAfterImage = false;
    Bitmap beforeImage;
    ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        //Hide Notification and Action Bars
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.add_progress_bar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        boolean cameraCheck = checkCameraHardware(getApplicationContext());

        if (cameraCheck) {

            StartCamera cameraLaunch = new StartCamera();
            cameraLaunch.execute();

        }

        Button closeCameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close_camera);
        closeCameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                releaseCamera();
                View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
                int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
                decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
                ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
                actionBar.show();
                finish();
            }
        });

        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera.takePicture(null,null,mPicture);
            }
        });
    }


    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        releaseCamera();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Hide Notification and Action Bars
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            //return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class StartCamera extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                if (useFrontCamera) {
                    mCamera = Camera.open();
                    mCamera.enableShutterSound(true);
                } else {
                    //Flip Camera
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(getApplicationContext(),mCamera);
            preview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview,0);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    }



    private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            int rotation = 0;
            switch (display.getRotation()) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0: // This is display orientation
                    rotation = 90;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    rotation = 0;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    rotation = 270;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    rotation = 180;
                    break;
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = ImageTools.toBitmap(data);
            bitmap = ImageTools.rotate(bitmap, rotation);

            if (!tookBeforeImage) {
                beforeImage = bitmap;
                ResetCamera cameraReset = new ResetCamera();
                cameraReset.execute();

                Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
                captureButton.setText("After");
                tookBeforeImage = true;

            } else if (tookBeforeImage == true && tookAfterImage == false) {

            } else {

            }




        }
    };

    /** A basic Camera preview class */
    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mCamera = camera;

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            this.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }



        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
            try {
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Camera Error", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }

            // stop preview before making changes
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
            }

            // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
            // reformatting changes here

            // start preview with new settings
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();

            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("Camera Error", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private static class ImageTools {
        public static Bitmap toBitmap(byte[] data) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        }

        public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap in, int angle) {
            Matrix mat = new Matrix();
            mat.postRotate(angle);
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(in, 0, 0, in.getWidth(), in.getHeight(), mat, true);
        }
    }

    private class ResetCamera extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            mCamera.startPreview();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            ImageView beforeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.beforeImageView);
            beforeImageView.setImageBitmap(beforeImage);
            beforeImageView.setImageAlpha(100);

            //Trying to add programmatically still ends up behind Camera Preview
            ImageView newBefore = (ImageView) new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            newBefore.setImageBitmap(beforeImage);
            newBefore.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            preview.addView(newBefore,0);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to trying to load too large of a bitmap, it was quietly throwing a notice in the log as it was unable to create a texture. Reducing the bitmap's size solved the issue.